# How to edit html (tags), before being executed by CppWebBrowser

Tags: webbrowser-control, c++builder

I can't solve my problem, and I hope somebody knows how...

I have a component on my form TCppWebBrowser, and when I navigate to a URL, after the document was downloaded, in method OnDocumentComplete() , I'm trying to check and change html source of loaded document... before it being executed by browser.

I need that, because some websites have background sounds, and I want to parse html and remove tags or just remove text which contains sound files like *.wav , *.mid , *.swf, *.mp3 ... ect.

For example if html source have this line:

```
<NOEMBED><BGSOUND src="/images/ImagineCut.wav"></NOEMBED>
```

then, i change it to:

```
<NOEMBED><BGSOUND src="/images/ImagineCut."></NOEMBED>
```

or I can delete whole tag.

Using this way I want to mute webbrowser or even to stop playing sounds. Please take into consideration this method, because it will help me to avoid all kind of sounds after I edited html.. (before browser execute it)

That's what I tried to do:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::CppWebBrowser1DocumentComplete(TObject *Sender,
      LPDISPATCH pDisp, Variant *URL)
{

IHTMLDocument2 *pHTMLDoc;
CppWebBrowser1->Document->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLDocument2,(LPVOID*)&pHTMLDoc);
IHTMLElement *pElem;
pHTMLDoc->get_body(&pElem);
BSTR text;
pElem->get_innerHTML(&text);
text = Cleaning(text); //checking and changing html without souds
pElem->put_innerHTML(text);
pElem->Release();
pHTMLDoc->Release();

}
```

Comment: What's wrong with DLCTL_BGSOUNDS?

Comment: The problem is that websites have a lot of methods to attach background sounds, but DLCTL_BGSOUNDS didn't solve it successful for all kinds of background sounds. I already tried this method, and I can say it is not good, better if I clean html code by myself before webbrowser execute it, so I can remove sound extensions and webbrowser will not be able to play them.

Answer (score -1):

To do what you are asking, you would have to download the HTML file yourself from outside of the TCppWebBrowser component completely, alter the HTML as needed, and then push the new HTML into TCppWebBrowser using one of its IPersist... interfaces.  Examples of doing that have been posted in the Borland/CodeGear/Embarcadero forums many times before.

Comment: WOW..I received an answer so quickly, Thanks! :)

Comment: I can download HTML with TNMHTTP or TIdHTTP using GET() method, I can even navigate twice with CppWebBrowser, and get HTML code with above posted code, but the problem is that I can't successful push it to webbrowser. I never used before IPersist interface, please if you have an example then post here, or provide working link. I will try to read it from MSDN.
Anyways thanks for your reply!

Comment: As I said, there have been plenty of examples of using the web browser's IPersist interfaces to push HTML into the browser.  Search the archives at http://www.deja.com and http://forums.embarcadero.com.